# Using Sphinx to generate Python document using :glob:

Tags: python, python-sphinx, glob, toctree

I am new to Sphinx.

The file `/home/user/myproject/docs/source/index.rst` is as following:

```
My project contents:

.. toctree::
   :glob:

   *
```

I am getting the below message on running `$ make html` under `/home/user/myproject/docs/`:

```
checking consistency... /home/user/myproject/docs/source/design/index.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

What have I done wrongly? I would like Sphinx to automatically generate the structure depending on the directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a supported operation.

Fortunately, it's not a very desirable one either, since you generally want the parts of your documentation to appear in a particular order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to just dump all your source files in `source` without a folder hierarchy, this is possible. Alternatively you could write a routine and run it from the `Makefile` before the call to `sphinx-build`.

As Mike alluded to, `:glob:` will just pull files in alphabetically by filename. [See the docs here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html#directive-toctree).

> You can use “globbing” in toctree directives, by giving the glob flag option. All entries are then matched against the list of available documents, and matches are inserted into the list alphabetically.

If you want to use `:glob:` and maintain ordering with all your files in `source`, you'll need to prefix your `.rst` files with numbers.

**Example**

```
source
├── index.html
├── 1_intro.rst
├── 2_install.rst
└── 3_more-than-you-want-to-know.rst
```

Though, you will of course need to rename the files if you decide you want them ordered differently, rather than moving the order of an explicit list in `index.rst`.